# Can Azure Network Watcher be used to diagnose app services?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, virtual-network

We have an App Service running behind an Azure Gateway and Azure WAF. App service connects with 2 APIs

- One API is running in an Azure VM
- The other API is running in another App service

---

1. Can we use Network Watcher to identify the delay in requests?
2. If yes can we use 'IP flow verify' component of Network Watcher?
3. Which other component in Network Watcher will we use?

---

NB: The question is specifically about "Network Watcher" not other monitoring tools in Azure.

Answer (score 0):

1. Can we use Network Watcher to identify the delay in requests?

   - yes but you will not be able to identify at the [`packets level`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/network-watcher/network-watcher-monitoring-overview)
2. If yes can we use 'IP flow verify' component of Network Watcher?

   - [`yes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/network-watcher/network-watcher-ip-flow-verify-overview)
3. Which other component will we use?

   - For your app service, you can use [Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/overview) and [`Application Insights`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview)

Comment: Where is app service mentioned in the diagrams or in the article? It states VM, yes but not App SErvice. Also #3 Which other component in Network Watcher will we use? Just added 'Network Watcher' to the question.

Comment: You can use application insights for the appservice as mentioned in the 3rd point. You will use traffic analytics https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/network-watcher/traffic-analytics

Comment: application insights is not a feature of Network Watcher.

Comment: @BlueClouds yeah i am aware of that :) which is a separate service. Application Insights will give more metrics with your custom code on appservie than the network watcher

Comment: @sajeethatan As comment agree you could suggest that. Not sure if it is acceptable as an answer. I have edited the question